# Update multiple records with the same value from another table

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to update the field ID_T1 in the table T2 with the ID field of T1, but the only thing that joins them is the DESC field in both tables, which is a problem, since all updates I've tried returns "single-row subquery returns more than one row" because in T1 there is more than one record with the same DESC

T1

```
|DESC | ID |
|A    |  1 |
|B    |  2 |
|C    |  3 |
```

T2

```
|DESC | ID | ID_T1 |
|A    |  1 |       |
|B    |  2 |       |
|C    |  3 |       |
|A    |  4 |       |
|B    |  5 |       |
|C    |  6 |       |
```

Expected result should be:

T2

```
|DESC | ID | ID_T1  |
|A    |  1 |    1   |
|B    |  2 |    2   |
|C    |  3 |    3   |
|A    |  4 |    1   |
|B    |  5 |    2   |
|C    |  6 |    3   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You got it the the wrong way around ;)

```
UPDATE T2 d
    SET (d.id_t1) = (SELECT c.id FROM T1 c WHERE d.desc= c.desc);
```

Comment: Thank you, but that was a mistake while changing the names of the tables, the output of your code is the same "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: Then the sample data you provided for T1 is not correct, meaning you have more rows there! try ... (SELECT DISTINCT c.id FROM T1 c WHERE d.desc = c.desc)

Comment: The data in the tables is right , I just did an awful job with the examples, sorry. Should I delete the examples to make the post clearer? Using the DISTINCT the output is the same.

Comment: Yes you should clean up the mess :) If distinct did not work then I can only guess you are very confused :)